# How to use a TTE A310 minitel with RPi?

Tags: serial

I don't know if it's the good place to aks but I have now a Matra TTE A310 which is a minitel, and I'd like to make it communicate with a Raspberry Pi or Arduino. I tried to make the connections with DIN5 but nothing happens, I think the minitel is not reading input from the DIN5. The problem with this minitel is that there's isn't a "Fnct" button and I couldn't find any docs about it.

So my question is : "How to put the TTE A310 in teleinformatics mode so that it reads input from DIN5?"
Thanks

EDIT: I have a
"
Connection
End
"
Button and if I click it I heard a noise and a "C" appears on the screen, but no connection to the RPi/Arduino

Comment: I'm guessing nobody outside France knows what a minitel is. I've heard of them ... many years ago, but that's all...

Comment: Wiki says it was 75 Baud uplink and 1200 Baud downlink ... just the same as 
Prestel in the UK, and probably not easy to configure a PC or R-Pi serial port for. You may have to use TX on one serial port and RX on another, not many modern serial drivers handle asymmetric baud rates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minitel#:~:text=The%20Minitel%20was%20a%20videotex,near%20Rennes%20in%20Brittany%2C%20France.

Comment: Oh I knew minitels were french but I thought it was then marketed outside the country. Thanks for your answer, I'll try the serial rate thing

Comment: Questions on the *usage* of products including PC peripherals and telecommunications gear are not on topic; this particular SE site is for hardware-related *design* questions only.  Your question is really seeking input from someone with *knowledge of the product* which is not on topic here.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, FFS, a Minitel. Probably better suited for [Retrocomputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com)!

A number of things to check:

- The serial port settings: 1200 bits/s for sure (though it was configurable to other speeds on certain models), 7 bits, with parity (don't remember which)
- Try swapping RX/TX
- Levels. They're supposed to be 0-5V I believe
- Levels again, it's possible that 0V is 1 and 5V is 0 and not what you expected.

There are schematics for converters to USB or RS232 available here: https://www.jelora.fr/post/2020/02/25/Adaptateur-prise-DIN-peri-informatique-Minitel-vers-Serie-RS232-et-Serie-USB.html

Note that this is a very very old model, of the "Minitel 1" generation, which means only 40x25 Videotex mode, no 80x25 "télé-informatique" (VT100) mode (which was introduced in the "Minitel 1B"). The Minitel 1B and Minitel 2 were quite nice for their time (and cost), but the Minitel 1 is really very limited.

The "Connexion/Fin" key is used to start the modem connection (or end it). On a Minitel 1 you would use a regular POTS phone connected to the same line to dial the PAD/PAVI and then press on that key for the Minitel to take the line and start connecting (V.23bis, 1200/75 bits/s). It's of course completely useless nowadays.

Comment: I'll try this and ask the question again on retro computing this evening, thanks!